# alternative to wp_link_pages() that only shows link to last page

Tags: posts, wp-link-pages, nextpage

I plan to have posts with multiple pages that would receive updates (added pages) over time.

what i want to do is to display the direct link to the last page of the post on the main index.

for example, I have a post split into 4 pages using the  tag.

what i want to do is that instead of pagination (which I get using wp_link_pages) that looks like this--> [Page 1 2 3 4]

I'll only get 1 link and get something that looks like this --> [Jump to Page 4]

any way how?

Comment: Please go and reformat your question. Also show your code. Else there won't be a chance to reopen that question.

Comment: i don't have a code. i'm asking if there is a code to achieve what i am describing my 'example'...

Answer (score 1):

Crib a bit of code from [`wp-includes/query.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L3645) and bit from [`wp-includes/post-template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L671), add a little, mix and stir, and...

```
function url_to_last_page() {
  global $post;
  $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $post->post_content);
  $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);
  $numpages = count($pages);
  $ret = _wp_link_page($numpages);
  $ret .= $numpages;
  $ret .= '</a>';
  return $ret;
}
echo url_to_last_page();
```

`wp_list_pages` works on index pages so WordPress had to know how to build the links. I just had to find the relevant bits. That need to be inside a Loop, as it depends on the global `$post` variable. It could be edited to accept a parameter to make it more flexible.

Comment: sorry, but how do i add this to my theme..? ust new to using wordpress, or rather, new to making my own theme...

Comment: Put the function definition in your theme's `function.php` and call it where you want the link to display, which is what I did on the last line. It will only work reliably inside a Loop, be aware.

Comment: tried it,but nothing happened...  :(

Comment: 95% sure I tested this... exactly what did you do?

Comment: uhm here, my index file (http://pastebin.com/sKNGhvPV), and my functions file (http://pastebin.com/jebJ6pE8)

it won't show anything... if i tinker with the code though, it woud just show the default output of wp_list_pages...